# Zeroes and ones in binary number Scala

Tags: scala, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I have read some number of binary representation from a file, then I summed them up and tried to find the number of zeroes and one's occurrences.
The problem is that some digits get lost or whatever else happens, so the total number of digits in a sum is more than a sum of zeroes and one's.
Here is my code:

```
val binaryNums = Source.fromFile("path/task2.txt").getLines.map(BigInt(_)).toList
val sumOfBins = binaryNums.sum.toString
println("Zeroes occurrence " + sumOfBins.count(_ == '0'))
println("Ones occurrence " + sumOfBins.count(_ == '1'))
```

I would be really grateful if you helped me to find a mistake.

Update: File contents look like this (about 800 digits in each number)
[image].

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide a small example of input (file contents) and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

By default `toString` converts the number to its decimal representation. To convert to binary you have to provide the radix argument to `toString`:

```
val sumOfBins = binaryNums.sum.toString(2)
```